# Animating an NSStatusItemView

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

Struggling with this one. I have a custom NSStatusItemView that I'm trying to animate. I've added the following code to my status item view to kick off the animation:

```
- (void)setAnimated
{
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    anim.duration = 1.0;
    anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    anim.autoreverses = YES;
    anim.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    anim.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    [self.layer addAnimation: anim forKey: @"animateOpacity"];
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];  
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

When I call this method, nothing happens. Yet if I move this code to my `drawRect` method, then the view properly animates at launch. Not entirely sure what I need to do to be able to tell it to start animated after the fact but the above method is not doing it and I have no idea why! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok answer myself so the googles have record of the answer!

The problem was, kinda of, a lack of understanding of drawRect. When my setAnimated method calls setNeedsDisplay, it calls drawRect again, effectively undoing what is done in the setAnimated method.

There were two things I did to properly fix this. First, I modified the setAnimated method to accept a BOOL argument and set a isAnimated property on the view to that value. I then, in drawRect, check this BOOL value and do the animation if it is set to YES.

Secondly, it seems, you need to call [self setWantsLayer: YES] the first time the view is drawn. So I call this in drawRect the very first time it is run, so that later animation will work.